# Unable to install coremltools

Tags: pip, installation, coremltools

I am trying to convert a pb file to a coreml file. to do this i need to install coremltools. However, when i try to install it by pip it comes up with this error :
     ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement coremltools (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for coremltools

i have tried to install it in a python 2.7 environment, still no joy

pip install coremltools
Collecting coremltools
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement coremltools (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for coremltools
Rorys-MBP:~ roryhodgson$

Comment: Please name your OS and Python version, including if it's 32- or 64-bit. The project [publishes](https://pypi.org/project/coremltools/#files) wheels for MacOS X and 64-bit Linux, not for win32 and no source. Supported Python versions are Python 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason I could found out that explains why this is happening is that coremltools require python 2.7, make sure you are running it `pip --version`. If you just typed `pip install coremltools` the chances are that your machine (assuming it is running macOS) pip command is running the default version of macOS python which probably is 3.5.2 or greater.

I could fix this issue by creating an environment in which my python version was 2.7:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Create a virtual environment:

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 py27
```

Activate it:

```
source py27/bin/activate
```

Lastly, install coremltools:

```
pip install -U coremltools
```

When you are done just deactivate the environment running `deactivate` in the terminal and that's it.

All this is available at the following source: [satoshi.blogs.com](https://satoshi.blogs.com/ml/2017/06/installing-coremltools-on-macos.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you install from GitHub, then you will not need to install Python 2.7 or fiddle with virtual environments.

```
pip install "git+https://github.com/apple/coremltools"
```

The code above will let you install coremltools by cloning the Git repository.

Comment: Good idea but it gives different error: `No module named 'google'`. I copied just the last string of the traceback.